# Как отправить base64-форму?

Tags: c#, captcha

Rucaptcha.com просит отправить base64-форму в таком формате:

```
<form method="post" action="http://rucaptcha.com/in.php">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="base64">
Ваш ключ:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
Тело файла капчи в формате base64:
<textarea name="body">BASE64_FILE</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить и получить ID">
</form>
```

У меня есть мой ApiKey и картинка в BASE64. Как мне отправить это на сервер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, не легче использовать библиотеку для этого, к примеру [эту](https://github.com/mevoronin/rucaptcha-client)? Хотя... она в этом случае лишняя.

Ну а так, код примерно следующий:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest(CancellationToken ct)
{
    string data;
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://rucaptcha.com"); //Базовый адрес 
    var url = "/in.php"; //Нужная нам страница, на которую пойдет запрос

    using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] //для удобства можно использовать Dictionary<string, string>. Тогда тело будет ещё короче ["key"] = "YOUR_APIKEY", ["body"] = "BASE64_FILE"
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "YOUR_APIKEY"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("body", "BASE64_FILE")
        }); //Наше тело, которое при помощи FormUrlEncodedContent закодируется в нужное нам "тело".

        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content, ct); //Отправляем на нужную страницу POST запрос с нашем телом, также тут используется CancellationToken для грамотной отмены async методов.
        var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        data = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Все эти три строки добавлены тут для того, что бы получать данные в нужной нам кодировке (некоторые сервера к примеру выдают в неверной кодировке и может выдать ошибку). Вообще можно все 3 строки заменить на одну:
        //data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Тогда кодировка будет той, что выдает сервер.
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Думаю по комментариям разберётесь. Тут вроде все довольно просто.

Comment: Вместо `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` можно использовать `Dictionary<string, string>` - синтаксис будет немного компактнее: `new Dictionary<string, string> { ["key"] = "YOUR_APIKEY", ["body"] = "BASE64_FILE" }`

Comment: Опять велосипеды, есть готовая библиотека C# http://bohdash.com/works/Rucaptcha-CSharp/ с её помощью код займёт одну строку .

Comment: @DigitalCore Тут вы не правы, это не велосипед, а то, что будет частью вашей библиотеки. Если человеку нужно **просто отправить** запрос, то зачем ему лишняя библиотека с кучей лишних классов? Ведь это простейший запрос на простейший `API`. Я к примеру сторонник портативных приложений и как можно меньше сторонних библиотек, а если одним файлом, так это вообще шикарно!) Вы ведь потом зависите от них. Да, если библиотека развитая, много комьюнити, то ок, но другие.. А вдруг забросят? Что дальше? Весь код с нуля при отказе от нее?

Comment: Я не спешил бы с выводами, вес библиотеки 4 килобайта, и лишних классов там нет.  Теперь отвечу ан предположение "вдруг забросят" - в таком случае софт тс и так работать не будут что с библиотекой, что с велосипедом. :-) видно сразу не в теме.

Comment: @DigitalCore Я вам не про размер говорю, ну да ладно. Давайте закроем эту тему. Кому и чем пользоваться, каждый решает сам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ согласен, я просто указал на то что версия библиотеки сервиса, и библиотеки клиента одна, и если сервис прекратит своё существование - то не имеет значения каким образом передан пост запрос. Учитывая сам вопрос ТС больше чем уверен в том , что с библиотекой логика его кода будет более оптимальной.