# Как в c# получить web-страницу при статусе не 200 ОК

Tags: c#

Захожу в служебную страницу. При статусе 200 - всё ок. Получаю что-то типа 
`{ "packageId": "1", "STATUS": "success"}`
Захожу в служебную страницу с браузера. При статусе 400 - Получаю
`{ "packageId": "2", "STATUS": "fail"}`

При этом с# генерирует

> WebException "The remote server returned an error (400) bad request"

Можно ли в с# аналогично получить тело запроса, при статусе 400 (или другом) стандартными средствами?

```
 string DoHttpRequest(site) {
     HttpRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
     req.Method = "GET";
     WebResponse res =  req.GetResponse(); // Тут возникает ошибка
     byte[] q =  new byte[255]; /*Небольшой ответ*/
     int i=res.GetResponseStream().Read(q,0,q.Length);
     return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(q,0,i);
     }
```

Comment: Ну для примера любой хост с траляля на клавиатуре, например http://google.com/486478263

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `HttpClient`, к примеру [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799447/Как-отправить-base64-форму/799466#799466), вроде он не даст ошибку (хотя могу и ошибаться)...

Answer (score 0):

Ответ спрятан в исключении. Т.е.

```
string DoHttpRequest(site) {
  HttpRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
  req.Method = "GET";
  WebResponse res = null;
  byte[] q =  new byte[255]; /*Небольшой ответ*/
  try {  
      res = req.GetResponse(); 
     } catch (WebException e) {
       res = e.Response; // + Проверить на null
     }
  int i=res.GetResponseStream().Read(q,0,q.Length);
  return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(q,0,i);
 }
```